# SSO Umbraco 7 using UmbracoIdentity with MVC 5 Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on, umbraco

I have tried to use Single Sign On method to my Umbraco sites (Umbraco sites using UmbracoIdentity for authentication) and my MVC 5 Apps, but I get problem when authentication has expired in Umbraco sites, it did not automatically clear authentication session in my MVC 5 apps. It happens vice versa.

Is there any event or something else which will be trigerred when the session has expired in one app?

Thanks,
Delly

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco does not currently support MVC 5. There are breaking changes so I wouldn't recommend trying to get them to work together just yet. Umbraco 8 will be MVC 5 and probably soon, but they are reducing the number of DLL's first.

The way I would handle this is probably to use the request pipeline and check if session is authenticated each time. See more about the pipeline [here](https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Implementation/Routing/Pipeline/published-content-request-preparation).

Comment: Exactly the Umbraco sites still using MVC 4, the apps just try to sharing the authentication, it just work when the authentication session not expired